# Python queue only 1 item

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to store only one item (the latest). I would do it as follows:

```
thread 1:
queue.queue.clear()
queue.put (DATA, block = False, timeout = 2)

thread 2:
queue.get()
```

But what if thread 2 get at the same time when thread 1 clears the queue?

The second idea is to clear the thread 2 queue immediately after  get, but I do not want the queue to grow, it is unknown what size when thread 2 does not download ...

Thanks for Help!

Comment: Aside: what's the space about before `()`? In any case, it's hard to understand the context of what you're asking

Comment: Either thread 2 gets previously stored item at any time before clearing (even immediately before) or new item after it was put in queue. It can't happen at the same time.

Comment: I just want to put only one item in a queue.

Comment: The solution is to make the clear-and-put a single atomic action, so that thread2's call to `get` can't occur between the clear and the put. Either thread2 calls `get` before thread1 calls `clear`, or thread2 calls `get` after thread1 calls `put`. The third option (get is called between clear and put) is not allowed.

Comment: @roganjosh probably a typo, however that's still valid python.

Comment: @jfaccioni it's not a typo, it's a consistent pattern on their function calls. I never said that it wasn't valid Python but it's not idiomatic for sure. EDIT: They edited out two of the examples so we're comparing different things

Comment: @MichaelButscher The problem is that thread1 is performing 2 separate actions; there is no single atomic clear-and-put operation (assuming `queue.Queue` from the standard library). Without extra precautions, thread2's call to `get` *can* occur after the clear but before the put.

Comment: @chepner This "get" call is blocking anyway if the queue is empty.

Comment: True, which is OK as long as there's only one producer thread.

Answer (score 0):

You want to prevent anyone else from accessing the queue between clearing it and putting a new value in the queue. You can accomplish this using a lock.

```
lock = threading.Lock()

def clear_and_put(queue):
    with lock.acquire():
        queue.clear()
        queue.put(DATA)

def get(queue):
    with lock.acquire():
        return queue.get()
```

If thread1 calls `clear_and_put`, it will either immediately get the lock, or wait until thread2's call to `get` completes. Once it acquires the lock, any call to `get` will block until the queue has been updated and the lock is released.